# Fill in a group table

Tags: abstract-algebra

Givens:

A:

> $a^2 = a \to a = e.$
>
> $ab = a \to b = e.$
>
> $ab = b \to a = e.$

B:

> Every row of a group table must contain each element of the group
>   exactly once.

Problem:

> There is exactly one group on any set of three distinct elements, say the set $\{e, a,
> b\}$. Indeed, keeping in mind $A$ and $B$ above, there is only one way of completing
>   the following table. Do so! You need not prove associativity.
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
>  & e & a & b \\
> \hline
> e & e & a & b \\
> a & a &  &  \\
> b & b &  & 
> \end{array}$$

Given:

$ae = ea = a.$

$be = eb = b.$

So, the group has identity $e.$

Suppose $ab = e$. Then $aa = b.$

Since $b = a^{-1}$, then $ba = e.$ So, $bb = a.$

Both $a$ and $b$ have inverses.

Thus:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & e & a & b \\
\hline
e & e & a & b \\
a & a & b & e \\
b & b & e & a
\end{array}$$

---

Does it makes sense? Also, what's the point of $A$ in the givens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final table is correct, but you haven't excluded the possibility of other tables.

The point of A is that it's one particular way of deciding what the entries of the table **have** to be (instead of guessing at what they *could* be).  For example you know $a \neq e$, so the first part of A tells you that you can't have $ab = b$.  Since the second row must contain every element you get that $ab$ is either $b$ or $e$, but it's not $b$, so it must be $e$.

Comment: @SICP: I took a closer look at your argument, see my edit.

Comment: @ Jim, I think we have to confirm  $ab \neq b$ and $ab \neq a,$ correct? You took care of the first one. Let  me think about the second one.

Comment: Suppose $ab = a$. Then $b = e.$ We know it's not true since it's given that $eb = be = b.$

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly where the given stuff in A comes in.